# Optional query parameters for Android Room

Tags: android, dao, android-room, optional-parameters

I have the following DAO with a query:

```
@Dao
public interface BaseballCardDao {
    @Query(
        "SELECT * FROM baseball_cards " +
        "WHERE brand LIKE :brand " +
        "  AND year = :year " +
        "  AND number LIKE :number " +
        "  AND player_name LIKE :playerName " +
        "  AND team LIKE :team"
    )
    LiveData<List<BaseballCard>> getBaseballCards(
        String brand, int year, String number, String playerName, String team
    );
}
```

The `String` parameters are "optional" in the sense that I can pass `"%%"` to match all rows due to the `LIKE` operator. But I cannot do this with `year` since it is an `int`. One solution is to add two different `@Query` methods, one with the `int year` parameter and the other without. Is there a more elegant way to create an optional parameter with Room's `@Query`?

Comment: What would your method signature be for one where `year` is optional? Would you be keeping this signature and using some magic `year` value that means "ignore the year"? If so, you might be able to do something like `AND (year = :year OR -1 = :year)`, assuming `-1` is your magic value.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, keeping the signature and modifying the query is along the lines of what I had in mind. Will you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 14):

It is a late answer but as I have faced it recently, I wanted to share my simple (but silly!) trick for those who are looking for it.

As @CommonsWare has said, we can add an `OR` statement that checks for null to it and then simply make our optional parameters nullable and pass `null` for them.
For example, your query would look like:

```java
@Dao
public interface BaseballCardDao {
    @Query(
        "SELECT * FROM baseball_cards " +
        "WHERE (:brand IS NULL OR brand LIKE :brand)" +
        "  AND (:year IS NULL OR year = :year)" +
        "  AND (:number IS NULL OR number LIKE :number)" +
        "  AND (:playerName IS NULL OR player_name LIKE :playerName)" +
        "  AND (:team IS NULL OR team LIKE :team)"
    )
    LiveData<List<BaseballCard>> getBaseballCards(
        @Nullable String brand, @Nullable Integer year, @Nullable String number, @Nullable String playerName, @Nullable String team
    );
}
```

Or more declarative using kotlin and optional parameters:

```kotlin
@Query(
    """SELECT * FROM baseball_cards 
        WHERE (:brand IS NULL OR brand LIKE :brand) 
        AND (:year IS NULL OR year = :year) 
        AND (:number IS NULL OR number LIKE :number) 
        AND (:playerName IS NULL OR player_name LIKE :playerName)
        AND (:team IS NULL OR team LIKE :team)"""
)
fun getBaseballCards(
    brand: String? = null,
    year: Int? = null,
    number: String? = null,
    playerName: String? = null,
    team: String? = null
): LiveData<List<BaseballCard>>
```

Edit:
Please consider that this solution is useful for non-nullable fields. If the field is nullable and you want to look for the records which don't have a value for the field, this is not the correct way of querying and you may consider dynamic query creation.

Comment: In my original code, I used `int year` instead of `Integer year`. Using a wrapper here might be a better solution than the SQL hack suggested by CommonsWare.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you a reason you didn't modify `brand LIKE :brand` to add a NULL check?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice No, It seems that I have missed it! thanks for your attention. edited.

Comment: This is an awful approach, because it may mess up the whole result-set. The question actually asked for a "more elegant way" ...now please explain to me how this would be more elegant than defining individual methods and switch them externally?

Comment: @MartinZeitler It was not meant to be an "elegant" approach in that way. As room doesn't have a built-in support for it, it is a simple trick to not write 2^5 = 32 functions for each possible form of optional parameters and also using the `Query` annotation. Surely, it has performance overhead and if we want to employ the best approach, we need to write the raw query manually.

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar its not necessary about being elegant (for me at least), its about being correct. This solution will give an incorrect result to the query

Comment: @user1202032 could you please give an example in which a wrong result is produced?

Comment: It doesn't work in case argument is an array unfortunately :(

Comment: @XZen Yeah, I myself wrote custom queries for those cases. But you may achieve it using some tricks like: `WHERE coalesce(NULL, NULL, :theArray) IS NULL OR column IN (:theArray)` which I'm not sure would be working and don't believe is a clean way.

Comment: @momt99 Thank you for advice, unfortunately cannot make it working with room - in my case `(COALESCE(NULL, :myArray ) IS NULL) ` is becoming `(COALESCE(NULL, ) IS NULL) ` at runtime (when I check logs) in case I provide empty array as myArray argument. The only working way I found is to pass 'special' array with only one element and just compare it like `WHERE (:myArray) = (-1) OR (col IN (:myArray)). It's very ugly and inefficient I guess. Another way could be passing 'myArray' size as a separate parameter.

Comment: @momt99 nice hack, but might return wrong result, as said above. Imagine the case: you want to fetch all items where 'brand' is null; with this approach 'brand' condition will be neglected (":brand IS NULL" is fulfilled, check for "OR brand LIKE :brand" is omitted), and you'll get all items, with 'brand = null' and 'brand != null'.
But should work fine for the case when 'brand' column in Entity is defined as non-nullable.

Comment: @ernazm yeah, you're right. it doesn't work correctly in nullable cases.